# I keep getting "Your database connection has been reset. Any pending transactions or session state has been lost." in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have recently installed Oracle SQL developer (version: `20.4.0.379`) and after changes in the query or during typing a new query I am getting the following error.

```
> Your database connection has been reset.  Any pending transactions or session state has been lost.
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: How often/quickly? The database session may be being terminated when it hits its idle timeout; or something in the network or a firewall may be dropping the connection, possible also based on a timeout; or your network might be dropping in and out...

Comment: Try out version 21.2.1 https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html there were some jdbc bugs that may have caused this in earlier versions and it should be better now

Comment: @AlexPoole It happens very often, after you edit 2 words you will get this message.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem, I closed all the anti-virus software and it get well.